# Setting page for testing in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm developing an `ios` application in which there are many `UIViewcontrollers` .
Every time fix a bug on nth viewController and run it, I need to navigate throughout the n-1 `ViewController`  then I land to my nth `ViewController`.

I want to implement some logic using which I can directly land to my nth `viewController`.

Comment: are you using storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done just by setting you window's `rootViewController` to that `UIViewController`.

Problem will occur if that ViewController was getting some data form previous ViewControllers. This could be solved by putting some static data to you destination ViewController.

Its just an option I discussed, it may have some challenges to serve your purpose. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: there are several parameters which are coming from previous viewControllers,I want on master view using which I can setup parameters and landing viewController.

Comment: Depends on which type of data you are getting, if that is some string or any serializable object you can use those data directly.